# Is there a publicly-accessible changelog for Mojave beta?

Tags: mojave, beta

I have an Apple Developer account, but it is not a paid account - I'm not really a developer, I just like to be able to see what's going on.

Therefore, when I try to access https://developer.apple.com/news/releases/ to find what's new in - for this week, public beta 8 - I'm met with a link to developer beta 10, which I cannot access.

Nowhere can I find a similar link to the current public beta.

Do Apple provide any changelog for public betas?

*Note:* I don't need a blow-by-blow account of every commit, just the broad strokes.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, **no**.

Apple doesn't provide release notes for public beta software. However, a comprehensive release notes report is available to registered developers enrolled in paid developer program (I am a paid registered developer).

As you mentioned, you are not looking for release notes from a developers perspective, but just need the **broad strokes** on what has changed. May I suggest looking through the one of the various blogs covering Apple news to get an idea.

One such popular site is [MacRumors](http://macrumors.com). They are generally quite prompt with any updates in the Apple ecosystem. MacRumors also share a birds eye view on the changelog with more user centric release notes.

See their blog post announcing [macOS Mojave 10th public beta](https://www.macrumors.com/2018/09/04/apple-seeds-macos-mojave-beta-10-to-developers/) which outlines the user facing changes introduced in the macOS Mojave and notes the changes introduced since the last beta. Each post generally also link to the post for previous release and can be traced back to the first beta.

Comment: Pity. I've looked at several of the MacRumors Mojave announcements & they're really just a rehash of the previous week's. They're telling you what to expect at release, but not what changed since last week. I know Apple will contact you if they have fixed a bug you previously reported, but other than that there seems to be no way to know what they think they may have fixed.

Comment: @Tetsujin, I think if you are much curious, resorting to seek info from a paid developer member may help. I can go through the Apple Developer license agreement and check if beta software is still covered under NDA. IIRC, the practise of imposing strict NDA has been relaxed since a few years ago. Once confirmed that that's the case, I'll be glad to share any release notes that you want. (I understand that's not what your original query is.)

Comment: That's very generous - but I don't think it's fair that you should take on the role of 3rd party distributor ;) I'm sure I will survive without this knowledge, I just really wanted to know if there was a generally-available resource my normally black-belt google-fu had missed. :)